# Razor Page areas vs folders

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I'm trying to understand Razor Page *areas*. Googling around, it appears that areas are just a way to create a directory structure within a Web application. (One that seems very ugly since it is done in a separate folder from the *Pages* folder.)

But I can easily create folders and subfolders under the *Pages* folder, and that keeps everything together and simple.

So why would using areas be better than regular folders?

Answer (score 7):

Areas were added to Razor Pages as a result of [some requests for the feature](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7487#issuecomment-379039843), seemingly by people who [wanted to be able to use Razor Pages in an existing .NET Core MVC application where areas were being used](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6926), or possibly by people who wanted to be able to port existing MVC applications over to Razor Pages more easily. The ASP.NET team also saw Areas as a good fit for [Razor Class Libraries](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/razor-class-library).

Beyond those use cases, there seems to be little to no practical or technical benefit from using Areas in a pure Razor Pages application.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the area name from a URL and still have the routes work correctly? I added quite a few of the scaffolded identity pages all under the "Identity" area folder, but I strongly dislike having "identity" in all of my apps URLs. i.e. instead of "/identity/account/login" I would like just "/account/login".

Comment: Yes, you can use the `AddAreaPageRoute` method: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#friendly-routes

Comment: Should I be using areas for anything other than the scaffolded identity pages?

Comment: I wouldn't. There's really no benefit to using them. They just add unnecessary complexity in my opinion.